# Multi-threading in ASP.net MVC3 with Code-First EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Been looking for a multi-threading solution for my application, but keep getting random `NullReferenceException` errors when I try, as opposed to when I ran each one consecutively and everything went smoothly.

What I'm doing is calculating a journey from one place to another, and then calculating the return journey.  The return journey calculation is just to use the same process, only with the departure and destinations switched.

Does this sound feasible to do this with multi-threading in an ASP.net MVC3 app with Entity Framework? I've seen a few articles where there seem to be problems with EF, but these sound like they are only an issue when DBContexts are shared on a page, whereas I've used Using statements round all areas where I need to access the database.  Anyone have any experience here?

The basic relevant code I have so far is this:

```
var outboundJourneyTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => BuildJourney(true));
var returnJourneyTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => BuildJourney(false));
Task.WaitAll(outboundJourneyTask, returnJourneyTask);
```

What I'd hoped was that each task would start afresh, but due to the null reference exceptions, I believe that in the second thread, it is trying to use arrays built in the first, and when it can't find certain elements, it throws errors.

Does this sound likely? Anyone know of a better way of doing this?

EDIT: I'm trying a different method of threading (see below) but there are really strange things happening with my arrays - looping through them differently and throwing errors

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(ThreadMethod1);   
t1.Start();

Thread t2 = new Thread(ThreadMethod2);
t2.Start();

void ThreadMethod1(object state)
{
    BuildJourney(false);
    ManualResetEvent mre = (ManualResetEvent)state;
    mre.Set();
}
void ThreadMethod2(object state)
{
    BuildJourney(true);
    ManualResetEvent mre = (ManualResetEvent)state;
    mre.Set();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How does your `BuildJourney` method looks like?

Comment: It is big - too big to post here as it contains a lot of other functions and calculations! It takes about 7-10 seconds to process, which is why I want them to run concurrently. It contains a few database calls, several calculations and returns a generic list of viewmodels.

Comment: But in such case we can hardly help you if we don't know what resources your call can share.

Comment: Yes I appreciate that.  i'll have to post the code up somewhere external - it's far too much to be able to make sense of in a code block here.  Now, I admit my understanding of threading isn't great, but I presumed that you would be able to make it so a new thread was completely separate i.e. they don't share any resources.  Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. "don't share any resources" is the key part - they can share resouces in a thread-safe (read-only, locked, not relying on state) manner.

Comment: Exactly what is your null reference exception error message?

Comment: @Marvc - just the standard "object reference not set to instance of object". It's a strange one - it's looking through an ArrayList for an id to check if it exists, and it does, so I'm not sure what the problem is.  Nothing is null in the debugger - It's just acting strangely, so i've put a try catch round it to bypass for now. I have a few loops through arrays that now aren't working as they were before and are throwing errors. I can see this isn't going to be easy!

Comment: @e-on - how are you iterating through arrays? foreach is not a thread-safe operation.

Comment: ah, that's disappointing.  I'm using rather a lot of foreach loops.  tbh, the whole app was built without the thought of using threading. If foreach loops aren't thread-safe, then that'll pretty much be the end of this idea!

Comment: @e-on - if you are not modifying these arrays (and their elements) while threaded code executes, try using for loops with local integer iterator - they should work.

Comment: Thanks Igor - I'm looking into Parallel.ForEach to see if it works ok. tbh I have a few things that aren't thread safe which is making my functions do all sorts of weird stuff, so I think I'll need to refactor, as Sean suggested below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Does this sound feasible..?" 
Yes, most certainly.

Easy to implement..... maybe not.

`Thread t1 = new Thread(ThreadMethod1)`

is an outdated but not necessarily deprecated way to do multithreading in .net 4+ framework. From what you have posted there is nothing indicating that you can't use tasks. Task factory is more modern way of managing Tasks in TPL but I have found it to have some quirks, personally. If I were you I would try doing this:

```
   Task T = new Task(() =>
                {
                   BuildJourney(true);
                });
                Task T2 = T.ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
                {
                     BuildJourney(false);
                });
```

This will ensure that T2 only runs when T1 comes back. Though, as Ladislav has said the method BuildJourney may not be thread-safe. This will at least get you one step further in determining where your thread failure is. You may want to investigate proper async and multi-threaded debugging. It is a little more complex than simply F5. Sites like pluralsight and the code project have very good tutorials on debugging and writing .net threaded programming.

You have a very good start here. Good luck!

Comment: Igor's comment about thread safe resources is definitely true. I would do some research here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx  in order to determine what you could use so those tasks could be run concurrently.

Comment: The more I noodle what is going on, the more I think that your BuildJourney class can't run multi-threaded. Not without some changes at least. The above code will work if you only want one instance of Buildjourney to run outside of the main thread at a time. You will probably have to refactor BuildJourney.

 Also, the more complex a method, the less likely it is to be thread safe.

Comment: Indeed - I think you're absolutely right there.  Judging by that MSDN library link you posted, there are quite a few things in all my processes that aren't thread safe, which would account for the bizarre errors I'm getting when I run it in a thread.  I think I will need to refactor, but I'm nearly at the point of going live with this project - I just wanted to make it faster, so whether I refactor now or after we go live is a choice I might make over a beer tonight! Thanks for your answer Sean, very helpful.

Comment: Very Nice lol. Close to production I would be weary of refactoring a large method for multi-threading. If speed is all you are concerned with you could try identifying some code hot spots. Have you used the code profiler and review systems built in to visual studio 2010/2012?  Those are a very good way to see where your code is getting hung up.  To be honest though a good multithreaded implementation can drastically increase your code performance. As a simple method maybe try to only use my above code so every BuildJourney call is in a thread by itself. Allowing the main thread to continue.

Comment: Just the sheer volume of data is holding things up - I've used the profiler to get the time down from a minute and a half initially down to around 7-10 seconds, so I've done ok. I use ajax and partial views so the data gets displayed as the algorithm completes each section, but it would be good to have both functions done within 10 seconds.  I may leave that for a "phase 2 amendment" though!

Comment: Definitley a good idea. There are some nuget Lint packages that might help even further. Is your data coming from a DB? If it is what kind? Do you have the ability to make any DB improvements?

Comment: It's sql server - the db calls are quick as it's indexed everywhere required, but the processing required adds the time on.  I'll check out the Lint packages though - that may help further.  Thanks again